# How to call (and use) onOptionsItemSelected from MainActivity in other classes

Tags: android, android-intent, android-actionbar, android-optionsmenu

I'm making my very first Android application but I ran into a problem.
I have over 8 different classes which all use the same actionbar.
Now in place of calling the method in every different class (and having a lot of double code) I would like to call the method of the main class in my other classes.

This is a part of my code for the onOptionsItemSelected in main.java

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.actionbar_new_income:
            Intent newIncome = new Intent(this, NewIncome.class);
            this.startActivity(newIncome);
            return true;
} 
}
```

Now I was wondering how I could call the method in another class (newIncome.java)
I have this so far, but it keeps saying I need to add arguments. And I ofcourse need to be able to detect which menuitem is clicked..

```
MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
        main.onOptionsItemSelected();
```

Any help please?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not do this. If you have common code then put it in a class (not an activity) that is accessible by any activity that needs it.

You will still have some duplication but this is normal.

A good way of reducing activity launch code is to add a static method to each activity that you can call which launches the activity it is in.

E.g in your `NewIncome` Activity you could have

```
Public static void Launch(Context c) {
    Intent newIncome = new Intent(c, NewIncome.class);
    C.startActivity(newIncome);  
}
```

You could then launch this activity from any other activity just by calling

```
NewIncome.Launch(this);
```

If required you can add parameters to the method and then add Extras to the Activity using these parameters.

Comment: I didn't phrase my question very well, so I edited it a bit.. I was talking about the classes, I have 8 classes where I would have to do the same eight times. Would there be a way to make a supermethod of onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menu) which I could use in every single class? Or is your way the best way?

Comment: If all of your menu options only start other activities then you can call out to a common class to handle this but if any of your menu entries do anything that is specific to an activity it should be handled by that activity.

Comment: They do in fact only start other activities, nothing else. But I would need to be able to detect which menuitem is clicked in every single activity and link it through to the correct other activity. What would be the best way to do this then? (note I already have an extend for something in all of my other classes so I cannot extend)

Comment: I have added a different answer. Is this more what you are asking for?

Comment: You can pass the menuitem clicked to the activity launched via Extras

Comment: I do understand what you mean, but can't I write the whole onOptionsIetemSelected only in my main activity and just call it up as a function in all my other classes? And then detect which ID of the actionbar is clicked to launch the according activity?

Comment: You could if you want hard to follow and messy code that is difficult to debug. My example does exactly that but moves the code to a separate class that does not depend on an activity. Remember that only one activity can be active at any time so to call code in one activity from another would require code gymnastics.

Comment: Alright this explained a lot to me, I'll go with your option then! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like the following example if your menu entries are totally independent of the activity in which they are contained:

In each activity

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  return CommonClass.HandleMenu(this, item.getItemId());
}
```

In a common class

```
public class CommonClass {

    public boolean HandleMenu (Context c, int MenuEntry) {
        switch (MenuEntry) {
           case R.id.actionbar_new_income:
             NewIncome.Launch(c);
          etc....
          ...
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your 8 classes are activities you may define a base activity with the `onOptionsItemSelected` which is the one where you put the elements in the actionbar you want. Then make the other activities derive from it.

Comment: I already extend my activities so I won't be able to do that? :s